# Poisson Process and flip a coin

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Consider a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Each time this process triggers, we 
flip a coin. Let X be the time at which the second head is flipped. Describe the random variable X, by giving its density function and cumulative distribution function.

If we flip this coin n times, and p be the probability when head will come. 
$P(X=2)= \sum P(X=2|N=n)$.I am not sure how to do this question. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant0\}$ be the Poisson process and define $T_0 = 0$, 
$$
T_{n+1} = \inf\{t>T_n : N(t) = N(T_n)+1\}.
$$
(The sequence $\{T_n\}$ are the "jumps" of the Poisson process.) One may show by induction that the density of $T_n$ is
$$
f_n(t) = \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^n}{(n-1)!} e^{-\lambda t}, \ t>0.
$$
(This is known as the Erlang distribution.) Now, let $\{X_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$, and $\tau=\inf\{n>0:X_n=1\}$. Then the density of $T_\tau$ may be computed by conditioning on $\tau$:
\begin{align}
f_\tau(t) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n\mid\tau = n}(t\mid \tau)\mathbb P(\tau = n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-\lambda t} (1-p)^{n-1} p\\
&= \lambda  p e^{-\lambda pt},
\end{align}
in other words, $T_\tau$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda p$. Now, $X$ is simply the sum of two independent copies of $T_\tau$, and so has Erlang distribution with parameters $n$ and $\lambda p$, that is,
$$
f_X(t) = \lambda p(\lambda p t)e^{-\lambda p t},\ t>0.
$$